# Natural language command language

Tags: command-line, nlp

I'm interested in developing a natural language command language for a domain with existing rules. I was very impressed when Terry Winograd's [SHRDLU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shrdlu) showed the way (the conversation below is 40 years old! Astonishing). Can we do better now and if so where can I get examples?

> Person: Pick up a big red block.
>   Computer: OK.
>   Person: Grasp the pyramid.
>   Computer: I don't understand which pyramid you mean.
>   Person (changing their mind): Find a block which is taller than the one you are holding and put it into the box.
>   Computer: By "it", I assume you mean the block which is taller than the one I am holding.
>   Computer: OK.
>   Person: What does the box contain?
>   Computer: The blue pyramid and the blue block.
>   Person: What is the pyramid supported by?
>   Computer: The box.
>   Person: How many blocks are not in the box?
>   Computer: Four of them.
>   Person: Is at least one of them narrower than the one which I told you to pick up?
>   Computer: Yes, the red cube.

I have an ontology for the domain so can reason over common problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also just encountered Regulus (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regulus_Grammar_Compiler) which has been extensively used by NASA.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [OpenCyc](http://www.opencyc.org/), a general knowledge base and commonsense reasoning engine.

Comment: Many thanks. I was aware of Cyc but not so aware of OpenCyc. Do you know whether people have interfaced it with NLP?

Comment: Maybe this presentation about adding a Cyc interface to the JavaNLP: http://nlp.stanford.edu/~ditka/cyc/cycPresentation.ppt

Comment: @luvieere Looks useful - not sure how much has been implemented

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the controlled English (ACE) that has been developed in the [Attempto project](http://attempto.ifi.uzh.ch).
It seems to have the required expressivity and flexibility.
The ACE parser parses ACE sentences into a first order logic formula (a variant called DRS) which can then be used for further processing, e.g. automatic reasoning.
The parser is available under LGPL, see the demo [here](http://attempto.ifi.uzh.ch/ape/).

Comment: This is very close to what I was looking for and you seem to have covered the worst of the tricky problems (negation, anaphora, etc.). Has it started to be deployed?

Comment: Yes, ACE is quite expressive when it comes to things like quantification, anaphora, negation, questions, etc. It also supports imperative sentences (like present in your example). I know that it has been used in many research projects, but I don't know how and how much it's been used elsewhere.